# Can anyone explain these conditions for the current mirror?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-mirror

> An important feature of the current mirror is a relatively high output resistance which helps to keep the output current constant regardless of load conditions. Another feature of the current mirror is a relatively low input resistance which helps to keep the input current constant regardless of drive conditions.

I don't really understand what it means here by load and drive conditions, and also why output resistance is high and input resistance is low.

Comment: The output is driving a current through a load. Suppose the output impedance of the current source/sink is one trillion-trillion-trillion Ohms. (High.) And suppose you hook up a 10 Ohm resistor to that. The 10 Ohms will make very very little difference to the current. The same if the load were increased to 10,000 Ohms. Still inconsequential. So the current would remain very nearly unaffected. High output impedance is a GOOD THING in current sources/sinks as most reasonable loads then have very little impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rbe = 26/Ic @ 25'C  {mA}  is low R in.
Rce = is high Z out as a common emitter current source
(current source with parallel Early Effect Leakage R)  This assumes Vce is not saturated where hFE drops to 10% of max when tested Ic/Ib=10 but it is reduced and doesn't matter that much.

[**Here is a simulation** with interactive switches](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcZoIQDgCwCYsOwOxjoEBsBICkll1CApgLRhgBQALiNtpstuAE5%20LftWZQQjGKQRhMCMgGYCmAegEIBEMPBAATegDMAhgFcANuw5d06PiEXZqIieMWxMM9IoSkBWgn9SXiloGTkFUmVVdU1tXQMTCysAdy5fe2wMsFJnVjSwIXBcQWFc8HziuxznIpquSsL%20R1KQAVIKgCVWlrASlupqTDoJQdRWACdW%20qauHgkqSEmHJ3Byx2puXmcqSqyOmbrypYBnKrXnEq2JCBNzE-plvrtr2evNuEqN88Usc9OHH9noDeO9wCA7g9lt9rr9QfNnEsCkVXijbBU0jD5jD0WwAOatXDVIqKSDbKCsAk4uzfUnkpYAD3AmnsxG0YCQvByIAAimwmYpemBFA4EFzuVyOjzsI0Sc1VgMvgr5dR2hj0gc%20nNxcI9tktUTWUrLjTVjNWAB7EC8YISTA%20XhIGAQTbWhysIA)

I added a trim resistor to get 1.0 mA and 10 mA on the left and the mirror on the right.  I also mismatched the hFE to show that it is **Vbe that forces Ic** and the mirror and not **hFE*Ib**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The output current of the current mirror varies with collector to emitter voltage, that is to say the output current varies with load resistance. This is due to Early effect.

Early effect can be modeled by a high resistance in parallel with the collector-emitter junction of the output transistor, this transistor acting as a current source. A non-ideal current source can be modeled by an ideal current source in parellel with a high resistance. If this parallel resistance (output resistance) is infinite (an ideal current source) then there is no Early effect and the output current doesn't vary with collector to emitter voltage. The lower the parallel resistance (output resistance) then the greater the Early effect and the more the output current varies with collector to emitter voltage. That is to say the more the output current varies with load resistance.

The lower the current source's parallel resistance, the more extra current is drawn through the load as the collector to emitter voltage increases (as the load resistance reduces).